# Load Rails After Static Page Load

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a rails app which is running rather slowly in Heroku and I'm assuming that the web page loads slowly because of the database and the rails. 
So what I'd like to make possible is have a piece of javascript which would only load the Rails content or a div which has the rails in it AFTER the whole page has loaded.

So something like this

```
LOAD HTML AND CSS, ONCE FULLY LOADED --> DISPLAY [JS SPIN][1] --> DISPLAY DIV OR RAILS
```

How would this be done?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "How do I have a static page which acts as an entry point to my Rails application which may take some time to spin up when accessed for the first time?"

Comment: Yes that sounds better

Comment: Is it always a slow page load or only when accessing it after a period of inactivity?

Comment: It's always a slow load, except if i remove the Rails

Answer (score 0):

You're question is extremely vague, but here is the direction you need to go

1. Remove the content from your view
2. Add a spinner gif to the view
3. in Javascript once DOM is ready, send [API request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to fetch this slow information
4. Make the gif spinner disappear
5. [Inject](http://api.jquery.com/html/) your information into the page

This is basically a Javascript question, not Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could have a static page which uses an AJAX call to populate the div from a route in the app. So you'd have a page in `public` that is pure HTML that loads jQuery, for example, and then makes the proper AJAX call to load in content from rails. That would be a request to a rails action that renders just a partial or a template without a layout. Depends on what you need but essentially:

```
def my_action
  render layout: false
end
```

And then the view template for `my_action`, alone, would be rendered in the response. The AJAX call from earlier would simply attach the HTML from the response to the container of your choice.

Does that help?